# make: *** No targets. Stop. error when trying to build Linux Tree Directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I just start contributing on Linux Kernel. I am following this guide https://youtu.be/LLBrBBImJt4?t=1052 . Up to that point I did required changes. Run the script to check for the code and it was error free. I then run `diff` and everything looked good. However when I did used `make M=` then directory I wanted to compile which was same as his, I got `make: *** No targets. Stop.` Error. So I can't build it.I checked some other answers already answered talking about changing makefile but I am not sure what to do.

Steps I did

1. Cloned https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
2. Created new branch
3. Edited one of the drivers
4. Run checkpatch script

What I can't get it working

make M= command because it gives above error. So I am unable to compile the driver I modified

Comment: Rather than link to a video, could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/512120/edit) into your Question what steps you took and what commands you ran?

Comment: I did some changes hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: What is your programming experience? What is your `C` programming experience? Have you considered contributing to a different part of the GNU project? (kernel programming as hard, error-prone, and will crash your machine)

Comment: I am CS Student so I am quite confident in programming. However I just started Linux Kernel Development so have to learn basics like how it is structured and all development process. So I can get on with it I think and I want to learn it anyway.

Comment: Are you running `make` from the top of the tree? `make` cares about where you are. If you used `cd drvers/...` and run `make` from there, it will likely not work as expected...

Comment: Also consider building the unmodified tree after checking it out (with `make menuconfig`, then `make bzImage` or similar commands) before you build a single module from that tree.